# Writing whole table data ( including relevant column names ) to Excel with using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

The issue is I'm trying to add/write column names with sequenced order over Excel environment and its cells ( e.g. first column name should be placed A1 cell and others following as B1, C1... ) and bind/write relevant data to under these columns. However the result that I want to achieve is not like above ( e.g. column names not following A1, B1, C1 order ) but placed in vertical order ( e.g. A1, A2, A3 etc. ) in .xls environment .

The sample code is that I've already working with to overcome this issue:

Firstly I'm taking column names and writing over .xls file:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=D:\dummy.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM dummy_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dummy_table';
```

And adding relevant data to same .xls file:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=D:\dummy_output.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[dummy_table]
```

How do I overcome to export whole table to .xls environment with using T-SQL in an effective way?

Comment: Use SSIS to copy data to a Excel from SSMS. - This is one option only.

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output as it's a bit unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to export a table from sql to excel. But ı need to create a new excel file. Then ı need to print header of columns. After that ı can export table values using openrowset clause. So now the only thing that ı need to do is exporting headers to new created excel file. I cant find a way how to achieve this header issue.

Comment: exporting data without column headers is a very easy job.
but the main task was getting column headers also in the first row of excel sheet.. (also export file type must be .xlsx not any .csv file type.)